R/mgcv: GAM where some dependent variables are function of each other
I am trying to create a model using mgcv of an explanatory variable based on multiple other variables that are cross-correlated, and have high concurvity.
Essentially, I want to explain a gas flux from leaves. The leaves emit this gas when they are stressed, e.g. when there is a lot of light and high temperature. However, the water concentration inside the leaf increases as a result of high temperature too. And once the water concentration is high enough, diffusion out increases and transports some of my gas of interest out of the leaves. Therefore, my gas flux is correlated to light, temperature and water concentration, which in turn is correlated to temperature. And temperature increases under conditions of high sunlight. This web of connections leads to very high concurvity, and I am wondering how such a scenario could be dealt with in a GAM? Thank you
